# How to configure Rhino Service Bus RemoteAppDomainHost programmatically?

Tags: servicebus, rhino-servicebus

I see a way to configure the DefaultHost with BusConfiguration(), but do not see a way to configure the RemoteAppDomainHost programmatically (without using a rhino.esb config file section).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override BeginStart from your bootstrapper and call UseConfiguration. Here's sample code that is working for me:

```
public class RemoteAppBootstrapper : AutofacBootStrapper
{
    protected override void OnBeginStart()
    {
        var busConfiguration = new HostConfiguration()
            .Bus( "msmq://localhost/endpoint.a" )
            .ToBusConfiguration();

        UseConfiguration( busConfiguration );

        base.OnBeginStart();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var cashier = new RemoteAppDomainHost(typeof(CashierBootStrapper))
                .Configuration("Cashier.config");
cashier.Start();
```

See https://github.com/BjRo/LearningRhinoServiceBus

Comment: JarretV - thanks for the answer, but I was looking for a way to avoid config files.